# Android TextView losing value after opening fragment

Tags: java, android, textview, datetimepicker

I have a method calling a DatePicker and a method calling a TimePicker which are both stored in a DialogFragment. Once the date or time are set the selected date/time is passed to a TextView on the main Activity. The problem I have is that if I set one of these TextView fields then go to set the other, the first one loses it's value.

I use the following methods to load the DatePicker/TimePicker:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View view) {

    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View view) {

    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

}
```

And the following are called from my DatePickerFragment / TimePickerFragment to set the labels / TextViews:

```
public void setDateLabel(String text) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_ridely);
    dateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
    dateTextView.setText(text);

    this.date = text;
}

public void setTimeLabel(String text) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_ridely);
    timeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
    timeTextView.setText(text);

    this.time = text;
}
```

I know the date and time pickers are working because they populate the labels / textviews as expected.

I read up about onSaveInstanceState / onResumeInstanceState and wen't through putting Log.d("RidelyApp", "method name") in each of these methods, and in the onCreate method but none of them are called during the process of setting the date/time.

EDIT:

I have found where the issue seems to stem from, and it's when I call the setDateLabel / setTimeLabel methods from the fragment. To do this I am using the following method:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    String pickedDate = "" + dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year;

    ((CreateRidelyActivity)getActivity()).setDateLabel(pickedDate);
}
```

If I replace `((CreateRidelyActivity)getActivity()).setDateLabel(pickedDate);` with `Log.d("RidelyApp", pickedDate);` then select the date / time it doesn't erase the previously selected value.

So the question becomes, what is the correct way to send the selected date/time back to my activity?

If there is more code required please let me know and Ill add it in.

Comment: why are you setting setContextView all the times. better to remove it.

Comment: Removing those resolved the issue. If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!